# PHP delete form for deleting data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-delete

I'm making a PHP script for deleting data out of a MySQL table. 
But it isn't working, could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Below you can see my two php scripts for deleting the information out the database.

First script

```
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// select record from mysql 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
var_dump($sql)
?>

<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Hardware verwijderen</strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>HardwareID</strong></td>
<td><strong>Merk</strong></td>
<td><strong>Producttype</strong></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['hardwareID']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['merknaam']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['producttype']; ?></td>
<td><a href="delete_hardware.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">delete</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop 
}
?>

</table>

<?php
// close connection; 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Second script

```
    <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="helpdesk_middenpolder"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="hardware"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE hardwareID='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "Deleted Successfully";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='testinlogpagina.php'>Terug naar de startpagina</a>";
}

else {
echo $sql . '. Details: ' . mysql_error();
}
?> 

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

**edit

result from var_dump: string 'SELECT * FROM hardware' (length=22)

Comment: Use mysqli_* or PDO, as mysql_* are deprecated as of PHP 5.5

Comment: @niekerd What is the error you are getting?

Comment: DELETE FROM hardware WHERE hardwareID=''. Details: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id']; ?>'' at line 1

Comment: Somehow `'id']; ?>'` is getting into your SQL query. Check your link code on the first page: `<td><a href="delete_hardware.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">delete</a></td>` Looks like the PHP tag is not getting parsed properly. I don't know why, it looks fine from here. Try `<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>` just in case the tags are getting lost there.

Answer (score 0):

as you are sending GET data like this

```
<a href="delete_hardware.php?id=<? echo $rows['hardwareID']; ?
```

here you are using `id` as the attribute/key

so get this value like below

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Changed it as you said above, but it still won't work. It now runs the else statement which says "ERROR".

Answer (score 0):

On delete_hardware.php

Change the lines

```
// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['hardwareID'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
```

To

```
// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE hardwareID='$id'";
```

Comment: Changed it as you said above, but it still won't work. It now runs the else statement which says "ERROR"

Comment: @niekerd Change the else statement to `echo mysql_error();` and then post the output back here.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id']; ?>'' at line 1

Comment: Update your question with the output of `var_dump($sql)`.

Comment: string 'SELECT * FROM hardware' (length=22)

Comment: Huh? The it should begin with `DELETE`, not `SELECT`.

Comment: Agreed. You should change the else statement to something like this `echo $sql . '. Details: ' . mysql_error();`

Comment: DELETE FROM hardware WHERE hardwareID=''. Details: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id']; ?>'' at line 1

Comment: @niekerd Your ID seems to be empty. I'm guessing your table structure. Do you have a hardwareID field and is it populated?

Comment: Yes I have it and it's populated

Comment: I think you should update your answer with your latest code version. Because I cannot figure out what is happening anymore.

Comment: What is the difference between `id` and `hardwareID`? This is why you are having problems. The first script uses `id` field, while the second is deleting `hardwareID`.